# Get PostgreSQL 8.4 listening endpoints on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL on Ubuntu and created a database.

Now, when my app tries to connect to an RDMS via localhost (127.0.0.1) tcp connection, I get an error.

Which command can I use to see on what endpoints does PostgreSQL engine listens for incoming connections?

Comment: What's the text of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo netstat -lnp
```

and then look for the `postgres` processes.

Since listening on `localhost` is the default for PostgreSQL, chances are your package decided to use a nonstandard port.